# Duplicate Records in salesforce

Tags: apex, data-loader, leads

I have created the Email field as External field in Lead , so i create so many Duplicate Records with email,I want to Merge the duplicate records into a Single Record

coding for two records Merging:

```
Lead L1 = [select id,Email from Lead where id='00Q2800000O2SaS'];
Lead L2 = [select id,Email from Lead where id='00Q2800000O2She'];
database.merge(L1,L2);
```

this i will merge for two Records into the single Id

I am Having Morethan 10 Records

for identifying the Duplicates using Apex code:

```
Set<String> ss = new Set<String>();
for(AggregateResult aggregate : [SELECT Email FROM Lead GROUP BY Email HAVING count(Id) >1]) 
   ss.add((String)aggregate.get('Email'));

List<Lead> duplicates = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :ss];

for(Lead lv:duplicates)
{
    System.debug('Duplicate Data----->' + lv.Email);

    **I want Merge Duplicate Records into single Record here in this line,what is the code anyone share the answer** 

}
```

I have identified the duplicates with same email id above code,it contains 4 Records,how to merge the four records into single Record.  Database.merge is not working for morethan two Records

Answer (score 1):

With database.merge() you can only merge 2 records. If you want to merge more then merge 2 and after that merge the 3rd with the resultant record and so on in a loop. Make sure u keep tab on the governor limits.

Comment: share the apex code@HSG,i am not able to find it

Comment: @Adrian Larson  please anyone share the apex code for above scenario